# Get content of tiny mce with many textareas on page

Tags: css, tinymce

```
     var inst, contents = new Object();

      for (inst in tinyMCE.editors) {
         if (tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent)
             contents[inst] = tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent();
```

I have 3 textareas on my page with 3 different id: #id1; #id2;#id3.

How can i make work that code for #id3? i've tried to replace inst with id3, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is suffiecient to call

```
var contents = new Object();

for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
    contents[i] = tinymce.editors[i].getContent();                  
}
```

Comment: Don't work.it set my content undefined.  i have 4 editors in my page, 2 for header and footer and the last for content. and i want to add in my content header and footer.I know how add that, but its are added in all editors.

Comment: can you log this oput to console inside the for-loop: console.log(inst)

Comment: what do you mean by "can't get last area"?

Comment: How can i contact you via email?

Comment: ovaron20 at gmx dot net